# A Tabs Component of React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I had scanned the Tabs component of react-bootstrap, but it was not a good choice, it mounted all the tab once the Tabs Component did mounted. So I use the child route to make a Tabs Component.

I have three tabs. For Example, tabA, tabB, tabC.

Specially, tabA and tabB have the same UI, but they request the different API

```
<Route path="tabs" getComponent={ProfitReports.flag.detail.default}>
    <Route path="tabA" getComponent={tabAorB}/>
    <Route path="tabB" getComponent={tabAorB}/>
    <Route path="tabC" getComponent={tabC}/>
</Route>

....

class Tabs extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Flex className="gm-tabs gm-paddingLR15">
                <IndexLink to="/tabs/tabA" className="tab" activeClassName="active">TabA</IndexLink>
                <Link to="/tabs/tabB" className="tab" activeClassName="active">TabB</Link>
                <Link to="/tabs/tabC" className="tab" activeClassName="active">TabC</Link>
            </Flex>
        );
    }
}

export default Tabs;
```

But it comes the problem.

**When I Click the tabA link, it works, But when I Click the tabB link, that nothing happen except the url has changed. No request, no new component init**

and I found the TabAorB component was not unmount, so I think maybe the problem was made here.

#### Requirement

I hope:

where I click the tabA link, it request the API1, and request the API2 after click the tabB link

Answer (score 0):

You may have some conflict or config error with your routes. However, for me, using Router doesn't look like a clean solution for tabs. Here is tabs component that is used in a project with bootstrap 3:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';


export default class Tabs extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.panelsContainer = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.panelsContainer));
    this.tabsContainer = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.tabsContainer));
    this.panels = this.panelsContainer.find('.panel-tab');
    this.tabs = this.tabsContainer.find('li');
    this.tabs.eq(0).addClass('active');
    this.panels.eq(0).css(this._styles.panelActive);
    this.panelsContainer.height(this.props.minHeight);
  }


  _handleClick(e) {
    const panel = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs[e.target.dataset.toggle]));
    const tab = $(e.target).parent();

    this.tabs.removeClass('active');
    tab.addClass('active');

    this.panelsContainer.height(panel.height());
    this.panels.css(this._styles.panel);
    panel.css(this._styles.panelActive);
  }

  _styles = {
    panel: {
      visibility: 'hidden',
      width: '100%',
      position: 'absolute',
      background: '#fff',
      border: '1px solid #ddd',
      borderTop: 'none',
    },
    panelActive: {
      visibility: 'visible',
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
    },
    panelsContainer: {
      position: 'relative',
    },
  };


  render() {
    let count = 0;

    const tabs = (
      <ul className="nav nav-tabs" ref="tabsContainer">
        {this.props.tabsNavItems.map((tab, key) =>
          <li key={key}><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick={this._handleClick.bind(this)} data-toggle={++count}>{tab.tag}</a></li>
        )}
      </ul>
    );

    count = 0;

    const tabPanes = (
      <div style={this._styles.panelsContainer} ref="panelsContainer">
        { React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) =>
          <div className="panel-tab" style={this._styles.panel} ref={++count}>
            { child }
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );

    return (
      <div >
          { tabs }
          { tabPanes }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Tabs.propTypes = {
  tabsNavItems: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
 _tabsNavItems = [
    { tag: 'Tab A' },
    { tag: 'Tab B' },
 ]
...

<Tabs tabsNavItems={this._tabsNavItems} minHeight={375}>
 <TabAContent />
 <TabBContent />
</Tabs>
```

Comment: But it seems no different to the Tab component of React-bootstrap.They mount all the content when the Tab component has been mounted.It's really a big waste.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem with requesting the api in the shouldComponentUpdate

Comment: But Actually it's a bad idea that requesting the api in the shouldComponentUpdate

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this today, it seems they have now fixed this issue at the `Tabs` of `react-bootstrap`, so you don't have to use `react-router` for this.

You should pass the property `unmountOnExit` on your `Tabs` component, and your components will mount only when they are active.

References:

- [Support unmountOnExit for tabs solution comment](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/129#issuecomment-204030541)
- [Improved Tabs API](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/1418)